# How to set cookies for webview in blackberry 10?

Tags: webview, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

can anyone please help me to set the cookies in a webview in BB10

below is my trial but it's not working

in qml

```
     WebView {
            id: webview
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
            preferredWidth: 700
            settings.javaScriptEnabled: true
            settings.imageDownloadingEnabled: true
            settings.webInspectorEnabled: true
            url: constants.GET_BASEURL_Value() + subCatValue
            onCreationCompleted: {
                app.setWebCookies(webview, constants.GET_BASEURL_Value() + subCatValue);
            }
            preferredHeight: 1100
        }
```

in cpp

```
    void ApplicationUI::setWebCookies(QObject* webObject, QString urlString) const {
    WebView* webview = qobject_cast<WebView*>(webObject);
    QUrl url = QUrl(urlString);
    WebCookieJar* m_pWebCookieJar = (webview->storage())->cookieJar();
    QSettings settings;
    QStringList cookies;
    cookies << "Cookie=" << settings.value("JSONID", "").toString().toUtf8();
    m_pWebCookieJar->setCookiesFromUrl(url, cookies);
    QStringList cookiesFromJar = m_pWebCookieJar->cookiesForUrl(url);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set it directly from QML:

```
webView.storage.cookieJar.setCookiesFromUrl(webView.url, ["test=test", "test1=test1"]);
```